# Why TcpClient.Connect is not throwing exception in async method even if it is running synchroneously

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

1. Why this code is not throwing System.Net.Sockets.SocketException even if no await is specified? (no server is listening at specified port )
2. Why Thread.Sleep(4000); is not executed?

   ```
   public class AsyncTcpClientDemos
   {
      private static readonly ILog Logger = LogProvider.GetCurrentClassLogger();

      public async Task ConnectTcpClientNoException()
      {
          Logger.Debug("ConnectTcpClientNoException() - start");
          var tcp = new TcpClient();
          tcp.Connect("127.0.0.1", 9045);
          Thread.Sleep(4000);
      }
   }
   ```

Method is called from within NUnit test:

```
[Test]
public void AsyncTcpClientNoExceptionTest()
{
    var asyncAwait = new AsyncTcpClientDemos();

    // TODO: find out why this is not throwing exception
    asyncAwait.ConnectTcpClientNoException();            
}
```

Comment: You can't just *ignore* the `await`. Try doing something like `asyncAwait.ConnectTcpClientNoException().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` - this will cause the exception to be thrown in your test method. Otherwise it's just discarded (left in the returned task to be more exact, but that doesn't help you any when you ignore the return value).

Comment: Or just asyncAwait.ConnectTcpClientNoException().Wait()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `async` method never throws an exception directly. Instead, if an exception is raised within the body of the method, the task returned by the async method becomes faulted.

The sleep isn't executed because the exception *does* prevent the rest of the method from executing - it's just that the exception is propagated via the `Task` instead of straight up the stack.

If you really want the first part of a method to throw an exception, you can split it into two. For example:

```
public Task FooAsync(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < y)
    {
        // This will be thrown straight to the caller, in the
        // normal way
        throw new ArgumentException("...");
    }
    return FooAsyncImpl(x, y);
}

private async Task FooAsyncImpl(int x, int y)
{
    // Any exceptions thrown here will be propagated via the task
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why this code is not throwing System.Net.Sockets.SocketException even
>   if no await is specified?

Exactly because of that. You aren't awaiting on the returned task. If you would of awaited, your would of seen the exception propagate:

```
[Test]
public async Task AsyncTcpClientNoExceptionTest()
{
    var asyncAwait = new AsyncTcpClientDemos();
    await asyncAwait.ConnectTcpClientNoException();            
}
```

Even by synchronously blocking you can see that (as suggested by @Luann) (just to make the point clear, don't actually use this):

```
[Test]
public void AsyncTcpClientNoExceptionTest()
{
    var asyncAwait = new AsyncTcpClientDemos();
    asyncAwait.ConnectTcpClientNoException().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

When you're using `async void`, you're forcing a "fire and forget" style of execution, where you completely discard the faulted task. This generates exactly the undesired behavior of swallowing exceptions. If you register [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll be able to see that when the task is finalized, this event fires.

> Why Thread.Sleep(4000); is not executed?

As John said, because the exception *does actually occur*, it's simply not reflected in the code you've written. Changing the execution to properly await on the task will show you that.

Comment: I used `async Task`. But same behavior with `async void` also.

Comment: @Andriy F Does an exception propogate?

Comment: No it does not in both cases

Comment: Do you have first chance exceptions turned on?

Comment: I'm not running this [tests] in debug mode

Comment: @AndriyF. Decorate your method with the `ExpectedException` attribute.